# How to fadeOut with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function in javascript:

```
function hid(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById("desc_div" + id).style.display = "none";
}
```

and I hope to use fadeOut effect instead of `display = "none"` by using jQuery

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function hid(id){
   $("#desc_div"+id).fadeOut("slow");
 }
```

See [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#desc_div" + id).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hid(id){
    jQuery("#desc_div"+id).fadeTo(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function hid(id){
    $('#'+id).fadeOut();
}
```

Also, [keep in mind](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) you can use fadeOut like: `fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )`, in case you want to specify the duration in milliseconds, and a function to be executed after the animation is over, or `.fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )` in case you want to specify an easing function as well.